# python extract values from an html table

Tags: python

I was thinking that lxml would be best for this purpose, but I'm open to better suggestions. 
Basically I want to extract the values from a table that looks like the following - (which is already in a python variable):

```
<thead><tr> .... </tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>col1val1</td><td>col2val1</td></tr>
<tr><td>col1val2</td><td>col2val2</td></tr>
<tr><td>col1val3</td><td>col2val3</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Now the thead and tbody tags are in the way and are not needed, so somehow I need to first slice off those tags, and then loop through all of the tr's one row at a time. I do need to perform an operation (insert to database) with each full row of data before moving on to the next row.

I think these first two answers are not working because the html table is in a unicode object format.

Comment: `lxml` seems like a good choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an example of using lxml.html:

```
from lxml import html

tree = html.fromstring('<html>Your HTML code</html>')
rows = tree.xpath('//table/tr') #update your table XPath here
records = []
for row in rows:
    cells = [c for c in row.xpath('./td/text()') if c.strip()]
    # do something with cells content
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regular Expression:

```
import re 

s = """<thead><tr> .... </tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>col1val1</td><td>col2val1</td></tr>
<tr><td>col1val2</td><td>col2val2</td></tr>
<tr><td>col1val3</td><td>col2val3</td></tr>
</tbody> """

lines = s.splitlines()
for line in lines[2:]:
    #print line
    match = re.findall("<td>(.+?)</td>", line)
    for m in match:
        print m
```